# Deterministic Decoder for Variational Bayes Autoencoder or RNN

Tags: variational-bayes

I was wondering if it is possible to use just deterministic function in the output layer of a variational Bayes autoencoder or RNN? Most of papers that I have read are using Gaussian Mixture Models (GMM) in the output layers but how about using just a MLP with TANH activation function in the output layer? I am talking about math not performance, is there any problem with that?

Answer (score 1):

For the objective function of the VAE, the ELBO, you need the expected log likelihood terms: $\mathbb{E}\left [ \log p(x_i|z) \right]$ for data point $x_i$. If you want to use gradient-based optimisation, this part needs to be differentiable, which is the case for e.g. Gaussian or Bernoulli log-likelihoods.

If you don't want your decoder to be Gaussian or Bernoulli or Gamma or so, but a point mass instead, the density will be a dirac function. This function assigns an infinite likelihood to its location, and zero everywhere. And as such it is not differentiable which again rules out gradient-based techniques. These methods are called likelihood-free methods, and there exists a large body of work on them.

There are ways around it. One way is to do it exactly as GANs, through a ratio estimator parameterised as a neural network. A paper exploring such methods in the context of variational inference is:

- Tran, Dustin, Rajesh Ranganath, and David M. Blei. "Deep and hierarchical implicit models." CoRR, abs/1702.08896 (2017).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. How about using a softmax function in the output? Does it solve the issue since softmax has also a distribution?

Comment: Yes, that would be a Categorical distribution. But it will induce a distribution, not a deterministic point!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers. I really appreciate it. I guess if I use the softmax without the hot vectors for target, minimizing the KL divergence between the target and output will be same as the maximizing the expected likelihood. Then, I can train my variational Bayes model.

Comment: I am sorry to ask you again. I understand your point but I still don't understand one thing. I thought maximizing likelihood is same as minimizing mean square error. Then, if that is true, we can substitute the log likelihood with MSE and train our variational Bayes model with deterministic decoder.

Comment: Maximising likelihood and minimising MSE is only equivalent for a Gaussian. So the decoder will not be deterministic, it will be a Gaussian distribution–and hence stochastic–over all possible output values.